# Pull-right even when Bootstrap Grid Columns are missing

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I want to always pull the last column to the right. I have 1 `4-column` group, 1 `7 -column` group and a single column.

My content is visible only on specific occasions. In the event that the content in the `col-md-7` is there, the last one gets pulled on the right fine. When it isn't there, it goes to the middle.

I am using AngularJS, along with bootstrap 3.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row mr10 ml10">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
                        ng-click="getData(data, LCtrl.Protection);"
                        ng-disabled="LCtrl.loading">
                        Run Query
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-if='LCtrl.loading'
                        ng-click="LCtrl.DataStop('Stoped By User')">
                        Stop Query
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7"
                    permission="[lCtrl.roles.disabled]">
                    <div class="pull-right mr10">
                        <span class="mb10"><b>Protection</b></span>
                        <label class="switch" style="margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: -6px;">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                ng-model="LCtrl.Protection"
                                ng-change="changeProtection()">
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <a href="//l-l/l.html?l={{lCtrl.licenseStr}}"
                        class="linkAtHeader pull-right"
                        style="position: fixed;"
                        target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Help
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: I know I could do this with offset. But then, when the content in the middle returns. the `help` button gets pushed. It overflows.. How do I handle that. I though about an inline conditional with ternary operators but then the HTML get's so crowded.

Comment: Use `ng-class` on the `help` button's div. Something like: `ng-class="{'col-md-1': otherContentVisible, 'col-md-8': !otherContentVisible}"`. Basically, you always need the columns to add up to 12, so use some variable to keep track of whether the middle element exists or not, and if it doesn't, increase the column width. Alternatively, don't actually remove the `col-md-7` from the DOM... keep it around and just toggle the content inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does make sense, but I do not want complex logic, inside my View. Even if I move that logic to the ctrl, it seems excessive. Thanks for your response though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code for col-md-1  `style={float:right;}`

Comment: Thnaks, that helped a lot.